# Excel adjustment of values - Max 3 iterations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following values in MS Excel.

Years: Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5, Y6  Y7 Y8 Y9 Y10

Income: -10, 2, 5, 6, -4, 8, -3, 6, 5, 2

Let us assume the Income values are entered in cell range C3:L3

Tax rate is 50% of Net Income. Tax will be Nil if yearly Net income is <= 0. Moreover, if the previous year or years income is negative, it may adjusted against current year's income. The adjustment cannot be done for more than 3 consecutive years. For eg. Loss of Y1(-10) can be adjusted until Y3 only. Y4 will not absorb any previous year's losses. Similarly  Y6 will adjust -4 from Y5 and the Net income for Y6 will be 4. The tax in Y6 will be 4*50% = 2

Using the above logic, the corresponding tax amounts(done manually) will be:

Tax: 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1.5, 2.5, 1

Can you build an excel formula that can compute the above Tax(shown manually above) and limit the adjustments? No helper rows or columns to be used. I guess Offset() may be used.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your formulae are in rows C3 to L3 :

I believe this would work C4:

```
=50%*MAX(0,C3+MIN(0,MIN(SUM(A3:B3),B3)))
```

And you can then extend it to the 10 cells.

Comment: Have clarified the question. The Income values appear in rows, say C3:L3. Need only 1 formula that computes tax.

Comment: You are very close. Year 6 and Year 8 are producing erroneous results. Y6 should be 2 and Y6 should be 1.5. The negative income of immediately preceding year is not taken into account.